# Cannot access the ASP.NET Core app deployed on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, asp.net-core-6.0

I am new to Docker and Kubernetes, and trying to deploy my ASP.Net Core 6.0 web application on Kubernetes with Docker image. I can see the service running with `type: NodePort` as in the last line of the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsgTM.png), but I cannot access this port on my browser at all.

[image]

I can also see the Docker container created by Kubernetes Pod running on Docker Desktop Windows application as in screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cje91.png), but I don't know how to access my deployed application from the browser. Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you  need to expose the service , so that it will allow external traffic. In order to expose the service use : `kubectl expose deployment <deployment> --type="Loadbalancer"--port=8080`, this will create an external IP.

Check the created external IP by using Kubectl get services  command.
If not visible, wait for a few minutes to get the service exposed. So, wait for a few minutes and check again the External IP will be visible .

Now access the service using `http://<EXTERNAL_IP>:8080`in the browser.

For more information Refer to this [Lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-kubernetes-aspnetcore#0) on how to Deploy ASP.NET Core app on Kubernetes.

Comment: I have also followed this tutorial, and the external_ip that I got is `localhost`. However, I cannot connect to the `localhost` yet.

Comment: Are you getting any error while connecting ? Post the error here.